# Exclude folder from analysis

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I look through the Internet and tried a million diferent ways, but didn't find an answer.

Is there any way to exclude some folders with source files from the Sonar analysis, when I use maven to launch it (e.g. mvn sonar:sonar)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the "sonar.exclusions" property to exclude source files using patterns: see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: thank you one more time! I just figured it out. I used "folder", instead of "folder/**" to exclude folder, subfolder and files and it, obviously, had no effect.

Comment: +1 This is obviously the correct answer - I will delete mine (although I got some reputation points ;-))

Comment: Just to point out that if you want to specify several exclusions, separate them with commas.

Comment: Folks, if I add **/folder/** shall I expect that *all* sub-folders from the folder will be  ignored too?